# Mask box animation with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How does one accomplish a solid image wipe, from bottom to top, in CSS? I dont think Im using the right keywords but I need to do this https://codepen.io/viljamis/pen/KdBoYZ without the gradient. This definitely has an answer I just cant find the right syntax.

```
slide-1 {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-mask-position 2s ease;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,
    rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%,
    rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%,
    rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%
  );
```

How can I modify this to be solid and bottom to top?

[image]

Comment: you want something like this? : https://codepen.io/antonietta/pen/wGpzPZ

Comment: No not at all - I want the image wipe, which transitions to a new image. But not the gradient. Just solid

Comment: You want to change the image with the transition, but not with the gradient  right ?

Comment: Please check the code below if it's helpful for you.

Comment: Like this? https://codepen.io/3rror404/pen/zYYbKKw

Comment: @Turnip yes, but I need it from top to bottom as shown in the gif. Tried changing the "to right" parameter and that broke it

Comment: Check the pen again.

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for your alternative ( You can check the snippet below with the hover mouse )

Code as below

```css
#cf {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cf">
  <img height="200px" width="200px" class="bottom" src="https://cnet4.cbsistatic.com/img/NlyoQRNtMD1kFL4pKE1LzkM6uhI=/940x0/2018/03/16/5b1ba726-2c4d-4163-b14d-ed97ff23f959/20180316-windows-10-background-01.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-70532741,width-643,imgsize-39687,resizemode-4/windows7.jpg" height="200px" width="200px" />
</div>
```

Comment: No thats not at all what I asked for. Please see image in edited question